# displaying a chm from menu

Tags: c#, winforms, chm

hey there,
so, basically i'm trying to get my .chm file to open in a help window when i click on 'view help' from the menu bar in a c# windows form. how do i do this? does the .chm need to be in the project's directory?
i tried using a helpProvider component and setting it's namespace to the .chm file, but when i run the app, pressing F1 doesn't bring it up...and i can't seem to figure out how to get the menu bar to display it.

thanks!
dave k.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HelpProvider` gets in the way here, use the `Help` class.  First off, putting the .chm file in the same directory as your EXE is a very good idea.  Project > Add Existing Item > select your .chm file so it is added to your project.  Select it in the Solution Explorer window, in the Properties window set Build Action = Content, Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer.

Sample code for your form:

```
using System.IO;
...

    private void showMyHelp() {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        path = "file://" + Path.Combine(path, "example.chm");
        Help.ShowHelp(this, path);
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == Keys.F1) {
            showMyHelp();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    private void HelpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        showMyHelp();
    }
```

Comment: i must say, you gave me exactly what i needed. your answer was very clear and concise! wish everyone answered questions like you do. wish i could give you more then just a single "this is useful"  Thanks!

Comment: Won't something like `Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\help.chm");` do the trick more simply...? Does `Help.ShowHelp`, and/or adding to the project, do something 'special'?

Comment: Well, sure, it uses the official help api and you stay in control over what is first displayed.  If Microsoft ever decides to display help differently then it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\help.chm");